# Switch Database in Entity Reference

Tags: 7, entities

The Drupal site is connected with two databases like this:

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'default',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
    'remote' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'remote',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

The remote database is in remote site, however in the new site I have identical content type for eg: Newsfeed.

The Newsfeed content type in new site has one more field **entityreference** and in this entityreference I would want to refer to the Node ID of the remote existent content of the same content type.

eg: In remote site, the content is "Hello my friend" of content type newsfeed and the nodeId is 12.

In new site, in same content type if I write a content "Hello all my friend" and in the entityreference field I want to give the nodeId of *Hello my friend* content from remote site.

All this I want to do it automatically with entityreference Autocomplete field. I know the entityreference Autocomplete can show the contents from same database while doing the autocomplete (given correct settings is done while creating the field). However is it possible to switch the database while entityreference autocomplete is working? If so, how?

The database switch is just to get the nodeId of the content from remote and it'll be switched back after the autocomplete.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly... how about this: at the beginning of your autocomplete function, connect to your remote, create an array with the nids you need, then switch back to new DB, and assign the nid values from the array?

Comment: I did the same, before autocomplete I have switched the database like `db_set_active('remote')` and after autocomplete the db is switched back like `db_set_active()`. This gives the **An AJAX HTTP error has occured with error code 500**

Comment: Try to switch back to active immediately after you load the array... something like this: 
`autocomplete_function { 
    set remote,
      populate array,
    set active,
    populate your autocomplete with your array
}`

Comment: did you manage to resolve this?